# Parallax effect not working in Android Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to create a parallax effect using Android's material design.
Please see the below main xml code...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mydomain.filterlistview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/search_view"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I wanted to hide the Toolbar when the RecyclerView is scrolled up and vice versa. But this is not happening.

Below is my build.gradle..

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

[Android Material Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQn86.png)
[Android Material Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcMMT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0`or above!

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for me.

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/search_view"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecycler ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager manager =new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
    MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(this);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Context mContext ;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context ctx){
        this.mContext = ctx;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycle_item,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder =new MyViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.txtView.setText("HELLO");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 30;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView txtView;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.naveenbm.parallaxstack">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```html
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**recycler_item.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE:** I have Removed `app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"` from your ToolBar and added app theme as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in menifest file.

Comment: This works, I forgot to change the ActionBar theme. But I have one more doubt. Its not hiding the toolbar completely.

Comment: try removing app:layout_collapseMode="pin" this line from your tool bar

Comment: can you share the screen shot?

Comment: Could you please check.. @Naveen Shriyan